# Why was my question closed for being "not about programming or software development"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75891767/16435223) about troubleshooting SSH errors on Stack Overflow today. The question got closed, and I want to know why it should be closed. As a disclaimer, I am not trying to complain but rather want to know why the question was closed and how I can use Stack Overflow better in the future.

The reason for closing my question was that it's "not about programming or software development." I read through the definition of it to understand what it means to be "about programming or software development." It says that questions on Stack Overflow "must be about either a specific programming problem, an algorithm, or a software tool primarily used by programmers." I personally consider SSH as a commonly used tool, which is why I am having hard time understanding why my question does not qualify to be opened.

Although the content of the question is still the same, I have edited my question to be clearer in case that's why my question was closed.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Comment: I'd probably have VTC based on lack of detail, but no part of your question involves programming, you're asking how to use SSH to use a web browser.  At the end of the day, we can't answer the question (maybe there's a firewall, maybe you have the wrong IP, maybe the remote machine doesn't even support SSH .. we don't have enough details to offer more than vague guesses).

Comment: SSH is not _primarily_ used by programmers.  "Commonly" and "primarily" are very different concepts.  macOS, Linux, mice, and keyboards are all also _commonly_, but not _primarily_, used by programmers.

Comment: I don't see how you use that tool in a programming context. Are you trying to script something over SSH? It reads to me as: I've setup SSH but I still can't connect. And that is something I face regularly but it is not a programming problem. It is dev-ops-y at best. Did you try Super User or looked over at Serverfault or even Devops.se?

Comment: The SSH-tag also has guidance what ssh questions are on-topic, listed on the top of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh I would ask this kind of ssh question on https://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: One of the highest-reputation SO users routinely answers these off-topic SSH questions. And they're great answers, so if he gets there before the close voters you're golden. Makes you wonder.

Comment: Using CLI != primarily programming.

Answer (score 25):

One of the close voters here.

Your question appears to be about simple usage of SSH, and the error message says a port is refusing connections. That does not appear to be a programming-related question to me, but rather a networking/general computer use question. It might be something a sysadmin, server, or devops team might deal with, but not particularly a programmer (when acting as a programmer, in contrast to situations where a programmer wears many hats, like in many small companies).